# How to store a over 16MB document in mogodb or any other best approach

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

In my project we have a requirement to store a document that exceeds the size of 16MB, my document definition looks like this

```
@Document
@Data
public class Execution {

  @Id
  private String executionId;
  private String queryId;
  private Type type;
  private String status;
  private Long startTime;
  private Long finishedTime;
  private String executedBy;
  private List<HashMap<String,String>> data;
  private Integer recordCount;
  private Attribute attribute;
  private String version;
}
```

Here field `data` is a list which holds more than 200k records and we need to fetch this document  from  mongodb by  paginating on the field `data` . But mongodb is not allowing  to store a document with size  more than 16MB. I tried storing each element of  the list  as separate document in the different collection, but as the documents  in the collection grows, the time taken for a executing the query is increasing

someone  please  suggest any workaround for storing the document with size greater than 16MB or any other  approach for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

the suggested way to work with documents bigger than 16MB is [gridfs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

Comment: This won't help; you can not query gridfs file contents.  Or the required metadata field will be as big as the file itself in the mentioned scenario.

Comment: as big as it's required for querying. There is no ideal solution here, but gridfs provides a built-in way to work with files bigger than 16MB that for example supports indexes. So the choosen solution should consider trade offs and be based on the goals

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to query against "data" field; It is better to store the value in the "data" field in an external storage (ftp, network storage, AWS S3 or similar) as a file. Then you only need to store the reference (URI or file path) of the file in the document.

Comment: In my project, we need to query against the data fields.

Comment: Then I can suggest you to simply divide your document into smaller chunks like 1 MB or 1K  - maybe.

So if the data field contains more than 1K (adjust for your needs) items; for each 1K entry insert a new document. This can help to solve performance problems caused when you insert each entry in a seperate document.